# Unable to open '/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000021f/DynamiteLoader.dm': No such file or directory

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play-services

How to fix the given below errors while using maps in my android studio java project. Any help would be appreciated.

> Unable to open '/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000222/GoogleCertificates.dm': No such file or directory >

> Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.>

> Unable to update local snapshot for com.google.android.libraries.consentverifier#com.steadyoil, may result in stale flags.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed: pkg=com.steadyoil, sha256=[98a6a68b3f9130328da89ac260298ca698eed37c4f821fab07f77c4221db96ec], atk=false, ver=231819044.true (go/gsrlt)
> at ajs.s(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@231819044@23.18.19 (190400-0):3)
> at ajs.get(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@231819044@23.18.19 (190400-0):2)
> at alc.g(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@231819044@23.18.19 (190400-0):2)
> at yz.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@231819044@23.18.19 (190400-0):1)
> at zb.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@231819044@23.18.19 (190400-0):0)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:463)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed: pkg=com.steadyoil, sha256=[98a6a68b3f9130328da89ac260298ca698eed37c4f821fab07f77c4221db96ec], atk=false, ver=231819044.true (go/gsrlt)
> at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3011)
> at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2995)
> at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2978)
> at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2920)
> at fe.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@231819044@23.18.19 (190400-0):2)
> at rx.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@231819044@23.18.19 (190400-0):4)
> at jl.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@231819044@23.18.19 (190400-0):2)
> at kj.t(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@231819044@23.18.19 (190400-0):2)
> at kj.u(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@231819044@23.18.19 (190400-0):3)
> at kj.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@231819044@23.18.19 (190400-0):2)
> at kn.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@231819044@23.18.19 (190400-0):78)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
> at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)>

Answer (score -3):

This means that there is not such file
Are you sure about the filepath of file?
maybe it looks like /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.package.app/file.dm
try to open this file in FileManager and check the file properties about real absolute filepath

regards